# Вызов процедуры

Tags: delphi

Есть две процедуры. Сначала описывается процедура 1 затем 2. При вызове из процедуры 1 процедуру 2 возникает ошибка что процедура 2 неизвестна. Как вызвать процедуру 2 из 1 если ее реализация написана позже?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как вариант, можно написать как-то так:

```
Procedure Proc2(<параметры>); Forward;

Procedure Proc1(<параметры>);
Begin
  // реализация процедуры 1, в том числе и вызов процедуры 2
End;

Procedure Proc2(<параметры>);
Begin
  // реализация процедуры 2
End;
```